Chainlink VRF subscription - not logical Fees
Need your help. I deployed my contract on BNB testnet. I used the keyHash:
0x8596b430971ac45bdf6088665b9ad8e8630c9d5049ab54b14dff711bee7c0e26
and VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus: 0xDA3b641D438362C440Ac5458c57e00a712b66700
Then called the random function from the VRF:
s_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest(..)}
The fees from the subscription fees for generating a random Word were around 0.025 LINK
When migrated to BNB mainnet, the fees for the same function are around 3.25 LINK
keyHash 0x130dba50ad435d4ecc214aad0d5820474137bd68e7e77724144f27c3c377d3d4
and VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus 0xd691f04bc0C9a24Edb78af9E005Cf85768F694C9
Please, need your help to advise what is better to use in this case.

Can you also show your smart contract source code and your subscriptions in testnet and mainnets? You mean fee for a single request in BNB mainnet is around 3.25LINK tokens?
